# Government policy toward open source software?

Tags: opensource, nsa, government

What are the government policies, specially security organizations, regarding open source?

Are they using these types of software?

Also, there are some papers related to this topic? I have found:

[Government Open Source Policies](http://csis.org/files/publication/100416_Open_Source_Policies.pdf)

[Government Policies on Open Source](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/csep590/04au/clearedprojects/Ferlo.pdf)

[Government Policies Supporting Open Source Software for the Mass Market](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Fabio_Manenti/publication/5157269_Government_Policies_Supporting_Open_Source_Software_for_the_Mass_Market/links/0912f5074857acd0e8000000.pdf)

Comment: Which government(s)? Do you expect that all departments have the same policies? The question is very, very broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why waste money into reinventing the wheel ?

That's for sure that defense organizations prefer to use software with accessible and analyzable code, whether it is open-source software or closed-source software with a special non-disclosure agreement signed with the providers allowing them to access the source code.

Compared to home brew code and closed source, open source software has the advantage of having been analyzed, corrected and improved by far more maintainers than any company could offer. As said at the beginning, it would just be a waste of money to develop the very same thing in a less reliable version.

However, a common thing would be to start from open source project and adapt them to suit some specific needs. These adaptation may range from some minor tweaks to some heavy developments.

In some cases, NSA might even be willing to redistribute such developments. [SELinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selinux) is a good example where the NSA started from the Linux open source kernel, modified it to add supplementary security features, then redistributed it as open-source to take advantage of the worldwide open source community.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but distributing an open-source software by security agencies necessarily does not mean that it is useful and these agencies try to help open-source communities. and also does not mean that developing an open-source by these agencies is equal to using it in their organization.

Comment: In September 2013, The New York Times reported that internal NSA memos leaked by Edward Snowden indicated that the NSA had worked during the standardization process to eventually become the sole editor of the Dual_EC_DRBG standard,and concluded that the Dual_EC_DRBG standard did indeed contain a backdoor for the NSA. As response, NIST stated that "NIST would not deliberately weaken a cryptographic standard."

Comment: Did I say it was "to help open-source communities"? I actually said it was "to take advantage of the worldwide open source community", it is not the same thing ;)

Comment: yes you are right. so it is true that they design a program, then use a special version of that in their organization, and maybe put a general version(as open-source) in public. but it does not mean these agencies search the IT world and find an open-source software in for example github and then get it ,check it, develop it and use it in their organization.

Comment: SELinux was the best example I could find from memory: they found the Linux kernel open-source project, got it, check it, develop it and hopefully used it within their organization. A little search shows that the same story also applies to [other open source projects](http://www.informationweek.com/applications/nsa-submits-open-source-secure-database-to-apache/d/d-id/1099972), this article explains how the NSA relied on several Apache projects (including Hadoop) to develop their own internal database management system.

Comment: 21. Does NSA have plans to use it internally?
For obvious reasons, NSA does not comment on operational uses.

Comment: 17. Is it approved for government use?
Security-enhanced Linux has no special or additional approval for government use over any other version of Linux.

Comment: These answers can not approve that NSA does not use SELinux, but also can not confirm that it uses it.

Comment: https://www.nsa.gov/research/selinux/faqs.shtml#I21

Comment: However we have not ideas in one direction,but thanks for your answer.

Comment: "[The agency said as far back as 2009 that it was using Hadoop to help develop a collaborative intelligence gathering system.](http://www.informationweek.com/applications/nsa-submits-open-source-secure-database-to-apache/d/d-id/1099972)" (same article as in my previous message): I think it is clear enough to confirm that NSA actually uses open source software internally.

Comment: Ok, and thank you, and since there are classified level in security agencies I think they dont use open source softwares in confidential and top secret places.

Comment: @Ali You might think that, but you're wrong. They don't use *anything* unless they can get access to the source code to review it; they *do* use Linux on JWICS, which is the DoD TS/SCI network (i.e. everything there is *at least* Top Secret). The US government doesn't have your strange bias against open-source.